# How do I close off edges after Canny edge detection for filling region in Matlab using imfreehand?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I need to close boundaries of a person I have got using a Canny edge detector. My aim is to be able to extract the filled (white) silhouette of the person and then save the image.

I read that [`imfreehand`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfreehand.html) might be used for freehand drawing, but how would I implement it for this purpose?

[image: Post canny edge detection]

(There might be multiple gaps in boundaries in my datasets so using imfreehand multiple times might be required)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the problem, you can use morphological operator *imdilate* and following *imerode*. *imdilate* will widen the boundary and make all boundaries connected, but all boundaries become thick. Then use *imerode* to go back to original width. 
Also you can use *bwmorph(img,'thin',Inf)* to do the second step that.

1. img = imdilate(img,strel('disk',3))
   [image]
2. img2 = imerode(img,strel('disk',2))
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try using morphological operators such as [`imfill`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfill.html) or [`bwmorph`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html) (with bridge)

```
BW2 = bwmorph(BW,'bridge');
```

Comment: This is what I was aiming to do in the end, but these will only work for a closed boundary which is not presently in the image yet. So I was looking for some way to close off the boundary.

Comment: Well you can use `imfill` and just use a seed location outside the bounding box of your figure. You then invert the fill to get the actual inside. Note that in some very odd cases where the bounding box size exactly matches the original size this won't work.